# VueJS: How to dynamically change a CSS class after a scroll position

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I am creating a webapp with vueJs and [bootstrap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/). I want to [change CSS class](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) of an element after a particular amount of scroll, Is there some vue way of doing it.

I want something like following:

```
<div :class="{classA: scrollPosition < 100, classB: scrollPosition > 100}">
</div>
```

One option I found is by using [vue-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-scroll), which seems promising, but [not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41096272/how-to-use-vue-scroll).

Is there some other native way as well to achive the same?

Comment: https://jsbin.com/mecekohete/1/edit?html,js,output would something like this work for you ?

Comment: @BelminBedak This will work if vue does not provide anything out of box, which probably it does not, Please post this as answer.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could try to make it like this

```
const app = new Vue({
  
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    scrollPosition: null
  },
  
  methods: {
    updateScroll() {
      this.scrollPosition = window.scrollY
    }
  },
  
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.updateScroll);
  }
  
})
```

You should also consider removing event listener when component is being destroyed, in order to prevent leaks:

```
destroy() {
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.updateScroll)
}
```

Comment: I believe `destroyed () { ... }` is valid for Vue 2, but in Vue 3 this has been replaced with `unmounted () { ... }`