# How to use vue-scroll

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a use-case where I want to change CSS class dynamically based on scroll postiion, which is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41095814/vuejs-how-to-dynamically-change-a-css-class-after-a-scroll-position).

I was thinking of using [vue-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-scroll) for this. I made following changes:

Installing using npm:

```
npm install vue-scroll --save
```

made following changes in **main.js**:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import vScroll from 'vue-scroll'
Vue.use(vScroll)
```

added following in one of the component, where I want to use it:

```
<div  v-scroll="onScroll">
   ...
   ...
   <p>scrollTop:<span>{{position &&  position.scrollTop}}</span></p>
   ...
   ...
</div>
```

and following changes in the component:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      position: null
    }
  },
 methods: {
    onScroll (e, position) {
      console.log('comes here ' + position)
      this.position = position
    }
},
```

However this is not working, I also tried to register this as a directive in **main.js**, like following, but this also did not help.

```
const app = new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  el: '#app',
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }, // Object spread copying everything from App.vue
  directives: {
    'v-scroll': vScroll  // tried 'vScroll': vScroll as well
  }
})
```

What can be possible reason of this not working.

Comment: I think you should set `v-scroll="onScroll"` on `body` tag

Comment: @BelminBedak I tried that as well, didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

<del>This lib doesn't seems to be in a very stable state, I managed to make it work using the `@scroll='onScroll'` or `v-on:scroll='onScroll` syntax. The position arg don't work tough, you need to use `element.scrollTop`.</del>

<del>It looks like the documentation is outdated, probably the syntax shown in the documentation is regarding vue 1.x.</del>

**EDITED**

Actually, I was completly wrong about this, `v-on:scroll` and `@scroll` will be handled by vue itself, no need for the vue-scroll lib. The vue-scroll lib is actually not working in the example I linked.

I guess you can use vue's built in scroll instead of the `vue-scroll` lib

**You can see a working example (tech support scam link removed)**

Comment: This is not working, neither I found something like this in vue documentation.

Comment: Is the example not working? The link I posted works for me, I tested with vue 2.x and it works too.

Comment: I didn't find anything regarding `v-on:scroll` in vue docs, but the `v-on` or `@` syntax works by adding this handler in the current element, so this will *basically* do `addEventListener('scroll', onScroll)` in the current element. Maybe your element is not *scrollable* and what you want is to add the event on the window object, then this approach will not work.

Comment: Yes, thats what I also just concluded, you code work as height of `div` is less than `section`, and you got that scroll location, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41097438/1610034) worked for me.

Comment: @TiagoHenriqueEngel your 'bin' (working example link) is not working anymore

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of instaling a package for a work which is already Vue provides by default.

In my case, `@scroll` didn't work but `v-scroll` did.

```
<div  v-scroll="onScroll">
<!-- stuff -->
</div>
```