# How to fix a div on scroll with vuejs?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I'm trying to fix a div but only when I'm scrolling down.

I have this template :

```
<div>
 <div class="header">Title</div>   // A header that will not be fixed

 <div class="sticky">Navbar</div>  // A div that will be fixed when scrolling down

 <div class="content">...</div> // The rest of the page
</div>
```

So the idea is that, when opening the page I have the 3 div displayed in the same order as the code (so header then sticky then content).
And when I scroll down, the sticky is fixed while I navigate the content.

I've tried to put a listener on scroll but I don't see how I can put a {position: fixed} only when scrolled and nothing when I return to initial position.

Comment: Just use `position: sticky`? [Most modern browsers support it already](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky).

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. The div isn't moving at all like with fixed

Comment: Well maybe you need to share an MCVE and see what's actually going on with your CSS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VueJS: How to dynamically change a CSS class after a scroll position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41095814/vuejs-how-to-dynamically-change-a-css-class-after-a-scroll-position)